# Weird SimpleXML issue - can't reference nodes by name?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm trying to parse a remote XML file, which is valid:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://feeds.feedburner.com/HammersInTheHeart?format=xml');
```

The root element is `feed`, and I'm trying to grab it via:

```
$nodes = $xml->xpath('/feed'); //also tried 'feed', without slash
```

Except it doesn't find any nodes.

```
print_r($nodes); //empty array
```

Or any nodes of any kind, so long as I search for them by tag name, in fact:

```
$nodes = $xml->xpath('//entry');
print_r($nodes); //empty array
```

It does find nodes, however, if I use wildcards, e.g.

```
$nodes = $xml->xpath('/*/*[4]');
print_r($nodes); //node found
```

What's going on?

Comment: I think you should use `children()` method to get it. `print_r($xml->children());`

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't explain the problem. I need to use `xpath`, and it works for other feeds - just not this one.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've got you wrong. Anyway, seems like `feed` isn't the root node.

Comment: In questions like this, you should always include a valid sample of the XML being parsed - a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We should not have to go to an external URL - which might disappear or change when a future reader finds the question - to find details vital to answering the question.

Comment: That said, I'd be willing to bet that your problem is with XML namespaces, and you need to use [`registerXPathNamespace`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.registerxpathnamespace.php).

Comment: @IMSoP - I would normally concur, but I felt that, since I had no idea which, if any, part of the XML was to blame, there seemed little value in lengthening the question with it. I felt the issue was more to do with my use of `xpath()`; from the answer below, though (and your last comment), it seems that, yes, the XML is partly to blame, insofar as it uses a namespace I'm not registering.

Comment: @Utkanos Well, one way would be to take a copy of the whole document, find an `entry` element, and delete everything that's not an ancestor of that element. Then test that the resulting small XML file still exhibits the problem (if it doesn't, great, you've found a clue!) and paste that instead of the link to the original copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike DOM, SimpleXML has no concept of a document object, only elements. So if you load an XML you always get the document element.

```
$feed = simplexml_load_file($xmlFile);
var_dump($feed->getName());
```

Output:

```
string(4) "feed"
```

That means that all Xpath expression have to to be relative to this element or absolute. Simple `feed` will not work because the context already is the `feed` element.

But here is another reason. The URL is an Atom feed. So the XML elements in the namespace `http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom`. SimpleXMLs magic syntax recognizes a default namespace for some calls - but Xpath does not. Here is not default namespace in Xpath. You will have to register them with a prefix and use that prefix in your Xpath expressions.

```
$feed = simplexml_load_file($xmlFile);
$feed->registerXpathNamespace('a', 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom');
foreach ($feed->xpath('/a:feed/a:entry[position() < 3]') as $entry) {
  var_dump((string)$entry->title);
}
```

Output:

```
string(24) "Sharing the goals around"
string(34) "Kouyate inspires Hammers' comeback"
```

However in SimpleXML the registration has to be done for each object you call the `xpath()` method on.

Using Xpath with DOM is slightly different but a lot more powerful.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->load($xmlFile);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
$xpath->registerNamespace('a', 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom');

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('/a:feed/a:entry[position() < 3]') as $entry) {
  var_dump($xpath->evaluate('string(a:title)', $entry));
}
```

Output:

```
string(24) "Sharing the goals around"
string(34) "Kouyate inspires Hammers' comeback"
```

Xpath expression using with `DOMXpath::evaluate()` can return scalar values.

Comment: Wow, would never have guessed you have to invent a namespace and use it for every XPath call. Thanks a bunch - totally solved my issue.

Comment: You don't invent the namespace - the namespace is `http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom`. You can read the element name as `{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}:feed`. This would be a lot of overhead and difficult to read. So they added the aliases. Aliases have only a local meaning, you register your own for the Xpath expressions and the XML contains different ones or defines a default namespace for elements. The Xpath engine and the DOM parser resolve the prefixes and namespace definitions and match the actual namespace.

Comment: Re: inventing, I mean the `a:` part, as you did it (if you use `foo:`, it also works, hence invent.)